# NgBootstrap modal not opening

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal using ng-bootstrap. My bootstrap version is 4.3.1. I have also entered the component modal entry in the "entryComponents" section. After doing all the above, I am still getting the error,

"No component factory found for NgbModalBackdrop. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"

Below is my app.module.ts code

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { ContainerComponent } from './container/container.component';
import { InnerContainerComponent } from './inner-container/inner-container.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { BoxesComponent } from './boxes/boxes.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';
import { SliderComponent } from './home/slider/slider.component';
import { LoginmodalComponent } from './header/loginmodal/loginmodal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    InnerContainerComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    BoxesComponent,
    FeaturesComponent,
    SliderComponent,
    LoginmodalComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    LoginmodalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The modal component code is:

LoginModalComponent

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginmodal',
  templateUrl: './loginmodal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginmodal.component.css']
})
export class LoginmodalComponent{

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

}
```

and below is my caller component code:

HeaderComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { LoginmodalComponent } from './loginmodal/loginmodal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  open(){
    this.modalService.open(LoginmodalComponent);
  }

}
```

Comment: any console error?

Comment: Yes. The error is mentioned above.

Comment: is your login component in another module?

Comment: no, it is in the same module

Comment: you need add  ` NgbModule.forRoot() i` in module import [https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/975]

Comment: One possibility could be you havent import NgbModalModule, as it is not defined in your imports section and in imports array

Comment: ok , i will try both the suggestions for now.

Comment: @Suryan, your suggestion worked Thanks !!!!.

Comment: @ram12393, it worked without importing it as @NgbModalMOdule.forRoot(). Is it needed to import it as for Root()?